# How to make a menu animate in

Tags: html, tailwind-css

so I'm working on a website with flask/jinja + tailwindcss. I have this html with a tiny bit of js for state management. Currently the sidebar just appears in it's full state instead of animating in like I want it to.

There's also a [codepen](https://codepen.io/cwkmaxwell12275/pen/KKXvogX) if you want to look at that

```html
<body>
    <!-- Top Bar -->
    <nav class="flex items-center bg-mainbg p-3 sticky top-0 z-50">
        <div class="flex items-center">
            <button aria-label="Button for opening the navigation menu" class="inline-flex p-3 hover:bg-valoreddarker rounded lg:hidden ml-auto transition ease-in-out duration-100 text-white" onclick="menuToggle()">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-5 w-5" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3 5a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM3 10a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM3 15a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                </svg>        
            </button>
            <a href="/" class="p-2 mr-4 inline-flex items-center rounded-lg">
                <img src="../static/images/Valobot logo raze thicckened.png" alt="Logo" class="h-10 mr-4">
                <span class="text-xl font-bold uppercase tracking-wide text-white">
                    Razebot
                </span>
            </a>

        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Side bar similar to discord dev portal -->
    <menu id="sidebar" class="left-0 max-w-full w-0 bg-black text-white h-screen transition-all">
        <li>
            <a href="/dashboard/{{guild_id}}/general">
                General
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/dashboard/{{guild_id}}/updates">
                Updates
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/dashboard/">
                Roles
            </a>
        </li>
    </menu>
</body>
</html>

<script>
    // Probably could do this in python but it was just easier in js

    // Basic Statemanagement for the dashboard
    function menuToggle() {
        let menu = document.getElementById("sidebar")
        menu.classList.toggle("w-0")
    }
</script>
```

P.S sorry for the long code block, html kinda be like that

Comment: css `#sidebar { transition: width .25s ease-in-out }` which if you'd like to provide a reproducible example in the code editor (the `<>` icon on the toolbar of the question text editor) or a codepen or something then we could show you more detailed, just provide your libraries to whatever example platform you choose and folks could perhaps display how to use cooler easing functions like `cubic-bezier` or keyframe animation instead for a cooler effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turns out, you need to toggle `w-full` class instead of toggling `w-0` class. because otherwise it doesn't want to animate.